Can't use AZ command in PowerShell
In the PowerShell version 7 - but I tried also with the system PowerShell - I have to run this command (see this Microsoft document)
npm run configure-sso 

and it requires to use az. So, I checked my PowerShell and the Az module is installed.

When I run the command, I get an error

node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing
inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with
the reason "'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. ".] {   code:
'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION' }


So, I tested and the command az is not recognized. I tried to install the Az module with PowerShell or the installer but still not working. I tried to install this module also with PowerShell 5. Apparently, the installation is running.

but at the end if I run az is not recognized.


you have a confusion between the Az PowerShell Module and the Azure CLI, different things. installing the Az Module doesn't install the Az CLI. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/what-is-azure-cli

Oh  I thought it was a module for PowerShell. Thanks
